# Summation of primes : Using Generator vs w/o Generator

Tags: python, generator, primes

Project Euler 10th problem:
Find the sum of all the primes below two million.
Well I came up with two solutions :

**USING GENERATOR FUNCTION**

```
def gen_primes():
    n = 2
    primes = []
    while True:
        for p in primes:
            if n % p == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(n)
            yield n
        n += 1
flag = True
sum=0
p=gen_primes()
while flag:
    prime=p.__next__()
    if prime > 2000000:
        flag = False
    else:
        sum+=prime
print(sum)
```

**W/O GENERATOR**

```
def prime(number):
    if number ==1:
        return -1
    else:
        for a in (range(1,int(number**0.5)+1))[::2]:
            if number%a==0 and a!=1:
                return False
        else:
            return True    
count=2
for i in (range(1,2000000))[::2]:
    if prime(i)==True and i!=1:
        count+=i
    else:
        continue
print(count)
```

Surprisingly, the latter (w/o g) takes *7.4 seconds* whereas the former (using g) takes around *10 minutes* !!!

Why is it so? Thought the generator would perform better because of fewer steps.

Comment: `primes.append(n)` that must be the thing that takes time. You don't need that.

Comment: the most performant solution being the sieve of Erathosthenes. Look that up.

Comment: These 2 solutions are not nearly equivalent; in the top one you use a `while True`, which is slower than a `for` loop. Also the bottom one you explore a much more limited range of numbers, so it's hardly surprising that this is faster

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop and calling `__next__` explicitly? Just use a for-loop, that is the *whole point*.

Answer (score 1):

Your generator is doing a lot of unnecessary work.  It checks all primes up to `n` when it only needs to check primes up to the square root of `n`.  Here is a modified version of your generator function with the unnecessary work removed:

```
from time import time

t = time()


def gen_primes():
    primes = []
    yield 2
    n = 3

    while True:
        is_prime = True
        upper_limit = n ** .5  
        for p in primes:
            if n % p == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
            elif p > upper_limit:
                break
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(n)
            yield n
        n += 2  # only need to check divisibility by odd numbers


sum = 0
for prime in gen_primes():
    if prime > 2_000_000:
        break
    else:
        sum += prime

print("time:", time() - t)
print(sum)
```

This takes 2.3 seconds on my computer.  The version without the generator takes 4.8 seconds on my computer.

If you're interested in a much more efficient algorithm for finding prime numbers, check out the Sieve of Eratosthenes. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rework of your generator code that's almost twice as fast as the non-generator code.  Similar to @DanielGiger's solution (+1) but attempts to be simpler and possibly a hair faster.  It uses multiple squaring instead of a single square root (may or may not win out) and doesn't need a boolean flag:

```
def gen_primes():
    yield 2
    primes = [2]

    number = 3

    while True:

        for prime in primes:
            if prime * prime > number:
                yield number
                primes.append(number)
                break

            if number % prime == 0:
                break

        number += 2

total = 0
generator = gen_primes()

while True:
    prime = next(generator)

    if prime > 2_000_000:
            break

    total += prime

print(total)
```

Here's an equivalent rework of your non-generator code that also attempts to be simpler and just a hair faster.  My rule of thumb is to deal with 2 and less as special cases and then write a clean odd divisor check:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    for divisor in range(3, int(number**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

total = 2

for i in range(3, 2_000_000, 2):
    if is_prime(i):
        total += i

print(total)
```

Also, your code generates an entire range of numbers and then throws away the even numbers -- we can use the third argument to `range()` to generate only the odd numbers in the first place.

In the end, the use of a generator has *nothing* to do with the general performance of your two solutions.  You can rewrite your second solution as a generator:

```
def gen_primes():
    yield 2

    number = 3

    while True:

        for divisor in range(3, int(number**0.5) + 1, 2):
            if number % divisor == 0:
                break
        else:  # no break
            yield number

        number += 2
```

The difference between the two solutions is one uses only primes as trial divisors (at the cost of storage) and the other uses odd numbers (pseudoprimes) as trial divisors (with no storage cost).  Time-wise, the one that does fewer trial divisions, wins.